# Simple file I/O C++

Tags: c++, file-io

We were given a prewritten (mostly) .cc file in which we were to write the implementation for two different functions. I was trying to do this without messing with the header of the function but can't seem to do it unless I am forgetting something since it has been awhile since I've done this.

```
void NumList::save_to_file(ostream& outs)
```

I tried using

```
string filename;

outs.open(filename.c_str());
```

to open the file but get the error

```
'std::ostream' has no member name 'open'
```

Whats the go around with this?

Comment: Literally, `std::ostream` does not have `open`. It is `std::ofstream` exclusive.

Comment: Presumably the file is open somewhere else - all you have to do is stream stuff to `outs`.

Comment: `open()` is only available for file streams. You should have your `save_to_file()` take `std::[x]fstream` depending on whether it's for input, output, or both.

Comment: assuming that the `save_to_file` signature is provided for you as part of the assignment, it would also be safe to assume that you will be passed a file stream that is already open

Comment: Looks like you don't need to open the file in that function. That is the responsibility of the function caller. All you need to do is the output statements.